# I want to compute the eigenvalue of this matrix. Help me, please.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, matrix-rank

\begin{pmatrix}
2na & -a & -a & -a & -a &  -a& -a\\ 
 -a& a+b & 0 & 0 & -b & 0 & 0\\ 
 -a& 0 & a+b & 0 & 0 & -b &0 \\ 
 -a& 0 & 0 & a+b & 0 &  0&-b \\ 
 -a& -b & 0 & 0 & a+b & 0 & 0\\ 
 -a&  0&-b  & 0 & 0 & a+b &0 \\ 
 -a&  0&  0&-b  & 0 & 0 & a+b
\end{pmatrix}

Above matrix is for $n=3$. There are block matrices $(a+b)I_3$ and $(-b)I_3$ above. I think the characteristic polynomial of this matrix for any natural number $n$ is calculated efficiently.

The rank is $2n$, so the characteristic polynomial should zero as the constant part. But I cannot calculate the determinant and I can't get zero when I put $t=0$ when I calculate $\text{char}(M)(t)$ for any $n$.

Also, I would like to know about the form, for example, spectral decomposition or Jordan from to compute eigenvalue of this matrix rapidly. Please give me a favor.

Comment: why don't you just put into a CAS?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because duplicate of this user's previous question, which did get an answer

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305384/how-can-i-compute-eigenvalues-or-characteristic-polynomial-of-this-matrix-pleas

Comment: meanwhile, the thing to do if you are unable to believe the answer by user1551 is to take, say, $a=5$ and $b=7,$ then get complete breakdowns of eigenvalues for $n=1$ and $n=2$ and $n=3$ By then it should begin to make sense.

Comment: Oh, yes. I did not know well about the prohibition of duplication. I wanted to know the answer for any n.